# Beamer specific pausing

Tags: beamer, floats, pause

I have a layout set in my mind for a beamer presentation where I'd like to put all of the figures at the bottom. I'd like to leave the figures on the screen at all times, but I'd also like to be able to pause some content in the itemize environment above the figure. From how pause works (as I've seen, I couldn't find more on it), this requires that I declare the figure *before* the \pause command. However, this puts the figure at the top. How do I either

1. Pause only certain content in beamer; or
2. Force a figure to go to the bottom.

Comment: You can add an overlay tikzpicture wherever you want. Look for “overlay” and “remember picture” in the pgfmanual.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to employ `tikz` and use an `overlay` picture with absolute positioning (which requires `remember picture`). (You could also use, say, `eso-pic`.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Pauses}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[above=1.5em] at (current page.south)
{\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
 \item bla
 \item blub
\end{enumerate}
\pause
Hello ducks!
\pause
\[E=mc^2\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]